# How many <tr> tags are allowed inside the <thead> tag in HTML table?

Tags: html

I have used two `<tr>`tags inside the HTML table  `<thead>`tags. The One `<tr>` tag contain `<td>` element  and other `<tr>` tag contain `<th>` element. So my doubt is how many `<tr>` can be allowed to use inside the `<thead>` tag.

Comment: Please provide your code sample

Comment: Added two <tr> inside a <thead> and confused about the number of <tr>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, you can include as many `<tr>` elements inside `<thead>`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead

> **The HTML `<thead>` element defines a set of rows defining the head of the columns of the table.**
>
> Permitted content Zero or more `<tr>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The `<thead>` element must have one or more `<tr>` tags inside.
See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp) for more information.

Comment: W3Schools is wrong *again*. Not since HTML5 replaced HTML 4.01 has there been a requirement for there to be at least one tr element in the thead element.

Answer (score 0):

One or more than one `<tr>` is allowed inside `<thead>`.You can add more than one `<tr>` inside `<thead>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `<tr>` tags inside `<thead>` tag

*but* if you are using loops & getting larger amount of data from databases and making too many `<tr>` tags then your browser is likely to crash